# What is the heat flux of fire?

Tags: thermodynamics

Let's say we have an object directly over a fire. How can we estimate the heat flux that the object receives? Is it the same for all fires? It seems like a complicated mix of convection from hot combustion products, and radiation.

Comment: "It seems like a complicated mix of convection from hot combustion products, and radiation." That's correct. How you estimate it? With difficulty!  If you want to design a heating system with a *known* heat flux, then you don't use an open fire, you design something that is easier to analyze and also likely to be more efficient - e.g. a condensing boiler.

Comment: I can give you some general parameters, if you think that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both @Alphazero and @JMac have pointed out, the complexities of a fire, particularly a natural fire, due to multiple interdependent physical, chemical, thermodynamic, etc. variables, makes it extremely difficult to determine the heat flux that an object placed directly over the fire would receive.

The following is intended only to provide you with some insight on these variables from a very brief perspective of the physical chemistry of combustion in fires and is in no way meant to be a rigorous mathematical treatment. It is based on material in Dougal Drysdale’s book “An Introduction to Fire Dynamics”, a book that has been used as part of some fire protection engineering curricula.

The figure below is a simplified representation of a burning surface showing heat and mass transfers. The following terms apply:

$\dot Q_{c}$ = rate at which energy (heat) is released in the fire (kW)

$\dot Q_{F}$ = the heat flux supplied by the flame fed back to the fuel surface ($\frac{kW}{m^2}$)

$\dot Q_{L}$ = heat losses expressed as the heat flux through the fuel surface ($\frac {kW}{m^2}$)

$\dot Q_{atm}$ =  heat lost to atmosphere (kW)

$\dot m$ = the rate of burning of the fuel ($\frac{kg}{m^{2}.s}$)

The diagram portrays the fact that only part of the heat released from the fire ($\dot Q_{c}$ ), would be available on the surface of an object placed above the fire. Some heat from the flame ($\dot Q_{F}$) must be fed back to the surface, primarily be radiation, in order to continue to convert the fuel at the surface into combustible gases ($\dot m$) necessary to keep the fire going. Some of that heat is, in turn, lost ($\dot Q_{L}$) as heat flux through the surface by conduction, convection, and radiation making it not available to convert a solid fuel to gas. And some of the heat released from the flame transfers to the surrounding atmosphere ($\dot Q_{atm}$).

The heat release rate ($\dot Q_{C}$) can be roughly related to the rate of burning $\dot m$ and the heat of combustion of the fuel by the following:

$$\dot Q_{c}= x.\dot m . A_{f}\Delta H_{c} $$

where

$A_f$ is the fuel surface area ($m^2$)

$\Delta H_{c}$ is the heat of combustion of the volatiles ($\frac{kJ}{kg}$) and

$x$ is a factor to account for incomplete combustion (<1.0) which is a function of the mixing of air drawn in from the surrounding atmosphere with the volatiles.

The rate of burning can, in turn, be expressed generally as

$$\dot m=\frac{\dot Q_{F}-\dot Q_{L}}{L_{v}}$$

Where $L_{v}$ is the heat required to convert the fuel into volatiles. For a liquid, that would be the latent heat of vaporization.

So very roughly you could say that the rate at which an object receives heat from the flame if placed directly over the flame would equal the heat release rate of the flame, minus the rate of heat fed back from the flame to the surface of the fuel, minus the rate of heat transfer from the flame to the atmosphere surrounding the object. Or

$$\dot Q_{c}-\dot Q_{F}A_{f}-\dot Q_{atm}$$

Dividing the above by the surface area of the object exposed to the flame would theoretically give you the heat flux that the object receives.

I should also point out the following statement from Drysdale:

*"...the rate at which energy is released in a fire ($\dot Q_{c}$) is the most important single factor which characterizes its behavior"*

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you guess, it is a complicated mix of convection and radiation (not just from hot combustion products, but also from the surrounding air being heated, lowering in density, and entering into natural convection).

This will depend on factors such as the size/shape of the object being heated, what is fueling the fire, surroundings, etc.

To estimate the heat received from the fire, I can think of a few options:

You could run a fairly complex multi-physics simulation that can incorporate the combustion process with the heat transfer and fluid dynamic processes to approximate the real scenario and hopefully give you a range to work with. (results will only be as good as your model is, and this may not be a simple thing to model *accurately*)

You could try to find experimental/tabulated information for a setup that is similar to yours, or that includes correction factors so that you can apply it to your specific setup. (results will depend on how reliable the external data is, and I have my doubts that there is reliable data for the exact setup you plan)

The third option is to run experiments yourself and have something to measure how much heat an object would receive.  The obvious drawbacks being that you actually have to do an experiment, which may not be feasible. (results will depend on how well you setup the experiment and measure the results)